# Django South: Adding a model field after a datamigration

Tags: python, django, django-south

Whenever I create a `datamigration` using Django South (but don't run it yet), and then subsequently create a `schemamigration` adding a new field to the model that was involved in that migration, the `manage.py migrate` task fails on the `datamigration`.

The reason for this is that the `models.py` file's class definition contains a new field definition that the `datamigration` doesn't recognize.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: There is a way to make the migrations recognize new fields in tables..

Comment: Would it be to manually add the new field(s) to the models dictionaries in the datamigration file?

Comment: No. There is a series of commands I used to do migrations with, after the initial migration, so the changes in the tables are recognized.

Comment: Would be good to know what those are :)

Comment: Here's the answer. I hope it works for you too ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In South Datamigration, you should newer reference to your models directly. ie

```
from myapp.models import MyModel # <- This is bad in datamigration
MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```

you must use the ORM obbject

```
orm.MyModel.objects.filter(...) <- This is good.
```